# How can I add multiple hyperlinks to a text, and remove some if they don't exist?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, href

I was using this code in html

```
<a href="Link1" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('Link2'); window.open('Link3');">Text</a>
```

Link1, 2, and 3 are from a table. Whenever an entry (for example, link 3) is blank, the html will open a blank page. I was wondering how I can avoid this.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know if a link is blank at the moment of html generation or not? If not - you can use an asynchronous call to update your method

Comment: How exactly is that HTML being generated?

Comment: I am using a template editor in DNN, and those links are generated from tokens. I am entering links in a separate form and the tokens get the links from that form. Thus sometimes, some of those entries can be blank, which is why I am having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you get your links from a database, you can try doing the following:

```
<a href="Link1" target="_blank" onclick="linkClick();">Text</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function linkClick() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<url to get data from>",
            success: function (data) {
                data.forEach(function (item) {
                    window.open(item);
                });
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

Put the right url for request and the `data` is expected to be an array of your links. If you've got another application design - let us know. Anyway it's a good way to separate your html from the business logic

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I might have asked the question a little wrong (very new to this) I am using a template editor in DNN and the links comes from using tokens. I use a separate page to enter links, and the tokens use the links from those entries.

Comment: You need to provide us with more details of whats going on?